# Existe alguma maneira de criar uma variável de ambiente pelo IIS?

Tags: windows, webforms, iis

Tenho uma aplicação rodando no IIS local e também em produção. Nessa aplicação, tenho uma funcionalidade onde, ao acontecer um erro, é enviado um e-mail. O problema é que não quero que isso acontece quando eu estiver em ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Pensei em determinar alguma variável de ambiente para fazer isso no IIS (porém quero que essa variável seja específica para essa aplicação).

Existe alguma maneira de definir variáveis de ambiente especificas para uma aplicação rodando no IIS?

Comment: já tentou no web.config ?

Comment: sugiro utilizar a opção debug mode, e ela estar habilitada somente no ambiente de teste: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/e8z01xdh.aspx

Comment: @RovannLinhalis hum... como eu faria isso? eu realmente estou mexendo com C# e derivados a pouco tempo, toda ajuda é bem-vinda.

Comment: acredito que seja só checar, com um if: `if(HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled
)`

Comment: @RovannLinhalis mas como é que o IIS vai saber que é debug ou não? Essa é a questão. Você está falando daquela flag `debug=true` do `compilation`?

Comment: sim, vou elaborar uma resposta, mas peço que faça um teste. Eu nao tenho como testar agora. Se der errado, me avise para remover ok ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode definir no seu `web.config`, na tag `compilation`, o atributo `debug`:

No ambiente de desenvolvimento:

```
<configuration>  
    ...  
    <system.web>  
        <compilation  
            debug="true"  
            ...  
        >  
        ...  
        </compilation>  
    </system.web>  
</configuration>
```

No ambiente de produção:

```
<configuration>  
    ...  
    <system.web>  
        <compilation  
            debug="false"  
            ...  
        >  
        ...  
        </compilation>  
    </system.web>  
</configuration>
```

Dentro da aplicação, você verifica se está em modo de depuração, e realiza o envio:

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled) 
{
    //envia o email
}
else
{
    //não envia email ou envia para outro endereço
}
```

Referências:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/e8z01xdh.aspx
https://stackoverflow.com/a/542896/4713574